# SSRS Report Builder empty header row

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, reportbuilder3.0, dynamics-business-central

I'm creating a report with a basic table:

[image]

This table will print a Direct Transfer:

[image]

Fields are populated by simple drag & drop from the left panel (dataset).

When printing the report, I can see a blank row in the header:

[image]

How can I remove that empty row? I didn't apply any spacing or anything to add a blank row...

**EDIT:**

The grouping part is by default, I didn't edit anything:

[image]

Comment: Assuming there is no grouping in the table, then I suspect you have a blank row coming from your dataset query. A blank row will not get generated for no reason. As a quick test you could sort by one of the columns in descending order and if the blank row moves, then you know it's the data that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Alan Schofield comment I've checked if the dataset came with an empty row by painting the table rows in yellow and table header in blue.

Confirmed that there was an empty row in the dataset.

Then as a simple (not clean) solution I've added a conditional visibility to the table rows:

```
=IIF(Fields!ItemNo_TransShptLine.Value = "", True, False)
```

In my case, all rows will have an "Item No.", so if there's a row without it won't print:

[image]